# Owner of the data and superuser should only be able to update the data using CBV

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

This is my UpdateView. As i have just started django. I am a newbie

**views.py**

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ProductUpdateView(UpdateView):
    fields = ('product_name', 'product_cost')
    model = Product
    def form_valid(self, form):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=self.object.pk)
    user = self.request.user
    if user == product.created_by or user.is_superuser:
        pass
    else:
        raise Http404()    #I tried this but it didn't work
```

I have created a superuser and a user. Superuser should be able to update all the product of both his and everyone else's but user should be only be able to update his product only.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^product/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$',
            login_required(ProductUpdateView.as_view()), name='product_update'),
]
```

I have a created a product using superuser, which has pk = 1. When i login with some user (Which not superuser) and visit the above url. This user is able to update superuser's product.

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name
    product_cost # This two fields and created_by
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
    User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Product", null=True)
```

Is there any way that own of the data can update that data and if user tries to access someone else's data it should Http404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this as [@Exprator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7925166/exprator) did.

```
def user_passes_test(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return self.object.created_by == request.user
    return False

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return super(RemitterUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    elif not self.user_passes_test(request):
        return redirect("remitter_search")
    return super(RemitterUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ProductUpdateView(UpdateView):
    fields = ('product_name', 'product_cost')
    model = Product

    def user_passes_test(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated or request.user.is_superuser:
            self.object = self.get_object()
            return self.object.user == request.user
        return False

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.user_passes_test(request):
            return redirect('someview')
        return super(ProductUpdateView, self).dispatch(
            request, *args, **kwargs)
```

i have created a function to check the logged in user is superuser and logged in or not, then passing the object instance to check if it belongs to the user or not

Comment: remove the () from the is_superuser and check once

Comment: it wont if the user is superadmin, please check the database to make sure the is_superuser column is 1 for the user you have logged in with\

Comment: if you are using django 1.10 + then remove the () from is_authenticated also